# Need help with arrays and loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Use a single-subscripted array to solve the following problem: Read in 20 numbers, each of which is between 10 and 100, inclusive. As each number is read, print it only if it is not a duplicate of a number already read. Provide for the "worst case" in which all 20 numbers are different. Use the smallest possible array to solve this problem.

here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20

int duplicate (int num[] );
int main ()
{
    int i, numbers[ SIZE ];
    printf( " Enter 20 numbers between 10 and 100:\n " );
    scanf_s( "%d\n" );

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE  - 1; i++ ); 
    {


int duplicate( int num[] )
{
    int i, hold;

    for ( i = 0; i <= SIZE - 1; i++ )
        if ( num[i] == num[i=1] ){
            hold = num[i];
            else
                hold = num[i+1];
        }

    printf( "%3d\n," num[ i ] );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  What's the matter with what you have so far?  Does it run, but produce an incorrect result?  Does it abort with some error?  Does it fail to compile?

Comment: @Angela there are some obvious problems with the code as posted: (1) The first `for` loop doesn't do anything because it has a semicolon before the opening `{` - i.e., there is no code in the loop; (2) The `if ( num[i] == num[i=1] ){` statement in the middle has `[i=1]` but should have `[i+1]` (unless you *want* an endless loop); (3) The three lines after the `if` are enclosed in the `if`'s `{ }` brackets *including the corresponding* `else` *statement* (which I assume won't compile); (4) You're assigning a value to `hold` but never use that value.

Comment: I've tried to reformat the code to be a bit more legible, though it involved some guess work because there's a few non-matching braces, and there appear to be two incomplete function definitions (`main` and `duplicate`).

Answer (score 4):

Your professor is, unfortunately, probably not smart enough to solve his own problem.  The smallest possible array for this problem is size 2 (Assuming a 64-bit data type, which is the largest the standard provides for.  With 32-bit integers it would need three elements, and with 128-bit integers, just 1).

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int_fast64_t visited[2] = { 0 };
    int inputs_left = 20;
    do {
        int input, slot;
        int_fast64_t mask;
        puts("Enter an integer between 10 and 100: ");
        if (!scanf("%d", &input)) {
            puts("That's not a number!\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (input < 10 || input > 100) {
            puts("Out of range!\n");
            continue;
        }
        slot = (input - 10) >> 6;
        mask = 1 << ((input - 10) & 0x3F);
        if (visited[slot] & mask) {
             puts("Already seen, it is a duplicate.\n");
        }
        else {
            visited[slot] |= mask;
            printf("%d is new\n", input);
        }
        inputs_left--;
    } while (inputs_left);
    return 0;
}
```

You are welcome to use this code in your assignment, if you are able to correctly explain how it works (I hope your professor taught you how to write comments).

Comment: ^ +1. The array size would depend on the type you take. If you take a `long long` or a `double` you can manage in an array of size `2` also.

Comment: I'm not smart enough to understand your solution, either, at least when it comes to storing 20 (or the first 19) numbers in an array size 3. You've assumed information not given in the question, i.e., that the numbers input have to be integers. If you're going to be "smart" and use bitwise operations to store more than one number in each slot in the array, I'd suggest that the smallest possible array size needed is a 1-element array (where that one element is, e.g., an object with a field for each number).

Comment: +1 Nice example of bit twiddling. @nnnnnn: It seems the question was formed with integers in mind. I'll agree that it wasn't explicitly given, but it seems like that's what was intended given by the code that was presented.

Comment: Good job, but you should modify the code to also support numbers between 10 and 19 or it doesn't satisfy the professor's requirements.

Comment: @NRS: I edited in the possibility of using a larger integer about the same time you left your comment.  Also, bitwise operations can't be used on `double`.

Comment: @David: Already done (I caught that mistake while re-reading the question).

Comment: @nnnnnn: There are 90 possible numbers, so this code is just using 90 bits to indicate for each number whether or not it was entered. To get a minimum of 90 bits, you need 3 int32_t values, or 2 int64_t values. Since the OP tagged this C++ (and not C), it could be solved even easier with a `std::vector<bool>`. :)

Comment: @Sven: The problem requires using an array, not a vector.

Comment: @N.R.S.: I didn't realize that `int_fast64_t` was standard.  Apparently it is, I'll change the program.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: but you are using an array, just not directly. :P Judging by the code this is actually a C question (not C++), but I was just pointing out you could use `std::vector<bool>` (which uses single-bit packing) to save some work, assuming the problem allowed it.

Comment: @Sven: I'm pretty sure that "use an array" doesn't mean "use somebody else's vector class, which probably uses subscripting on a dynamic memory area, which may or may not be an array".  It's lot likely that `vector<bool>` could do it more efficiently than this anyway.  And the goal here is for Angela to look up in her C or C++ textbook what the bit manipulation operators do, which using vector wouldn't accomplish.

Comment: @Sven - I understand how the code works, and it is nice code if you assume that the requirement to use an array meant literally declare one and use it in any manner at all, but if you're going to assume that why not declare a 1-element array and use it to hold an object that knows how to store (or even compare) 20 numbers? That better answers a question that wants the smallest possible array. Also, if you're going to take the question that literally it *doesn't* say the numbers will be integers so this answer, however clever, is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with, thanks for everybody's help:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define MAX 20

  int main()
  {
int a[ MAX ] = { 0 };  /* user input */
int i;                 /* counter */
int j;                 /* counter */
int k = 0;             /* number of integers entered */
int duplicate;         /* notify of duplicates */   
int value;              

printf( "Enter 20 numbers between  10 - 100;\n" );

      /* ask user for 20 numbers */
      for ( i = 0; i <= MAX - 1; i++ ){

    duplicate = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &value);

     /* decide if integer is duplicate */
    for ( j = 0; j < k; j++ ) {

     /* notify and stop loop if duplicate */
        if ( value == a[ j ] ) {
        duplicate = 1;
        break;
        { /* end if */



     /* enter number into array if it's not a duplicate */
        if ( !duplicate )
        a[ k++ ] = value;

} /* end if */
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

- The duplicate function is inside the main function.
- i is declared multiple times
- There should not be a semicolon after your first for loop.
- The hold variable is not being used for anything. It is only being assigned a value.
- num[i=1] - not sure what you are trying to do here, but the i=1 is setting i to 1.
- In your first for loop, your condition is i < SIZE - 1, meaning it will loop 19 times, not 20. It should be i < SIZE or i <= SIZE - 1.
- Your if statements should use braces ({}) for each if/else, or not at all.

  ```
  if (test) {
      // code
  }
  else {
      // code
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  if (test)
      // code
  else
      // code
  ```

As for the logic:

- You are only getting one integer, which you are not putting in the numbers array. You will need to get 20 integers one by one and check the array each time the user enters a number.
- The duplicate function should probably take a second parameter, the number that you want to check for. The if statement would check if num[i] equals the number you are looking for.
- Remember to initialize the array values and only check values that you have set. For example, when the user enters the third number, you only want to check the first 2 numbers in the array to see if it already exists.

PS: Please try to indent your code properly. Many people will not even try to help if it is not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

My C is pretty rusty, so here's a pseudo-code solution (since this *is* homework you should do some of it for yourself):

```
print initial prompt;

declare nums[ array size 20 ]; // I later assume a 0-based index
declare boolean found;

for (i=0; i < 20; i++) {
  // prompt for next number if desired
  read next number into nums[i];
  found = false;
  // compare against all previously read numbers
  for (j=0; j < i; j++) {
    if (nums[j] == nums[i]) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    print nums[i];
  }
}
```

Note: the question as stated doesn't say the numbers have to be integers. Also, it says "use the smallest possible array" - you could do it with a 19 element array if you introduce a non-array variable for the current number (since the 20th number read only needs to be checked against the previous 19, not against itself), but that makes the code more complicated.

See also the comment I posted above that mentions some specific things wrong with your code. And check that all of your brackets match up.